# Accessing OS-Level APIs with Flutter

Tags: flutter, service, operating-system

I was just wondering if Flutter has an interface to access OS-level APIs such as capturing keystrokes and mouse events, user info, screenshot, OS build, taskbar icon, fullscreen, etc.

I am thinking of something like a service application that listens to those events globally in the background even if it if has no focus.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it is not currently possible with Flutter. I opted to use JavaFX instead.

Answer (score 1):

Flutter is a **Portable UI Kit**. if there is a plugin available for any system level service or feature you can use that plugin to take advantage of that system service or feature, otherwise Flutter is just a Portable UI Kit that can only create a GUI to be drawn on a canvas on your target system. It's only the existence of the Plugins that makes Flutter into an app development framework